# Not being proper viewed in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, uiview, landscape-portrait

I have been successful in viewing app in portrait mode. What the problem is, when I view it in landscape, it doesn't seem to be proper. I have implemented this code.

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    return interfaceOrientation=UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    return interfaceOrientation=UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
   return interfaceOrientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Should I do anything extra? Is this code helpful to me?

Comment: @sch:Oh.....I have implemented this code in shouldAutoRotate..... and it doesn't seem to be proper means view of my app in landscape mode is not proper.....

Comment: Yes exactly....Have u had solution??

Comment: I edited my answer, but I need more info about the problem to detail it further if you still need help. 1) Do you use Interface Builder or do you create your view programmatically? 2) What are the changes you want to make to the view when the device is rotated? 3) A screenshot of the view may help a lot.

Comment: I have used Interface Builder. But sorry, I can't provide u screenshot bcz of privacy..sorry again... bt I tell u that I have used navigation bar...when I view app in landscape, it is viewed in almost left side..doesn't feet in simulator...and some controls are not visible bcz they are in downside...

Comment: @sch:Hey, I am newbie so didn't know what is bounty...I want to just checking it out and found this one...:) :),,,ur ans is absolutely correct....no worry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` into the following if you want to support all possible orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

If you want to support only: `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`, then change your code into:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

You don't need to look for the new orientation in `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` because you already have it as a parameter.

---

If you want to make the elements of the view repositioned when the device is rotated, you have to use their `autoresizingMask` property. Another option is to implement the method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

You can change `autoresizingMask` of the elements of the view in Interface Builder in the **Size Inspector**. Try experimenting with different combination until you get the result you need.

[image]

Finally, note that if your view is complicated or is radically different in each orientation, the best option is to use two xib files: one for portrait and one for landscape.

Comment: Done successfully,,,bt view is not proper..means should I make changes in frame??

Comment: Oh...thnx sch for solution...I will try this and keep in mind all these....:)and yup,,,this helps me a lot..thnx again..